# Python tuple access issue?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, pyparsing

I am using python pyparsing libary whose output seems to be tuple. However, when trying to access as tuple I get unexpected result.

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> aaa = (Literal('xxx') + SkipTo(':')  + Literal(':')('::') + Word(nums)('eee')).parseString('xxx : 123')

>>> aaa
(['xxx', '', ':', '123'], {'eee': [('123', 3)], '::': [(':', 2)]})
```

Here is what is strange:

```
>>> aaa[0]
'xxx'
>>> aaa[1]
''
```

I would expect `aaa[0]` to be the list:

```
['xxx', '', ':', '123']
```

and aaa[1] - the dictionary:

```
{'eee': [('123', 3)], '::': [(':', 2)]}
```

Why am I getting the unexpected? What is happening here? Thanks.

Comment: did you type aaa yet?  type(aaa)

Comment: >>> type(aaa)
<class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
>>> dir(aaa)
['::', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__', 'eee']
>>>

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045757/list-of-dictionaries-and-pyparsing/7047048#7047048  ParseResults objects can be treated like a list, a dict or an object. Or you can convert them using `asList()` or `asDict()`. But first try these accesses:  `aaa[0]`, `aaa['eee']` and `aaa.eee`. I am a little mystified that you have values in some of the named results that don't appear in the list, and why there is one named element with the name "::".  But those are tangential to this question.  If you print out `aaa.dump()`, you will see better details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has some great introspective abilities.  To determine what something is ask it

```
>>>type(aaa)
   <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
```

What can you do with it, methods and attributes

```
>>>dir(aaa)
   ['::', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__', 'eee']
```

I see it has a get method so

```
for each in aaa:
    type(each), each, len(each)

<type 'str'>
```

```
for each in aaa:
     type(each), each, len(each)



(<type 'str'>, 'xxx', 3)
(<type 'str'>, '', 0)
(<type 'str'>, ':', 1)
(<type 'str'>, '123', 3)
```

Now it is time to read the documentation

I will note that you created xxx and these other things using methods of pyparsing so you can ask what they are as well type(Literal) and learn about their internal magic dir(Literal) sometimes the answers are not so helpful, but usually you will not break anything by asking.

Bottom line, it does not appear that aaa is a tuple, I notice that it has some methods that are the same as methods of tuples but it does not have all of the methods a tuple has.

Comment: Thanks, anyway I can get all the information that is there in aaa. Like maybe converting to json? I desperately need all of it: keys/values with positions in tuples? Thanks again.

Comment: Class docs can be found online at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/, and the docs on ParseResults at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParseResults-class.html

Comment: Pyparsing classes are fairly well annotated with docstrings too, which are accessible using python's 'help' command, as in 'help(Literal)' or 'help(Literal.parseString)'. This will give you actual documentation beyond just the output of dir.